# Creating a custom QListWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a custom *QListWidgetItem* that I can insert into a *QListWidget*. I want it to contain a label and a button. I have tried looking up many examples and the code below is what I came up with:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <string>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtWidgets>

class myNewWidget : public QListWidgetItem{

public:
    QLabel *aLabel = new QLabel("hello");
    QPushButton *aButton = new QPushButton("Press");

};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    myNewWidget *newWidget = new myNewWidget();
    QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem();
    ui->dayRoutine->addItem(item);
    ui->dayRoutine->setItemWidget(item, newWidget);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I can't get this to work however. In the code, I try to create a custom *QListWidgetItem* by creating a class that inherits it. `ui->dayRoutine` refers to the dayRoutine *QListWidget* that I have in my ui. I added it via the UI designer hence no instantiation code. The error I get is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QListWidget::setItemWidget(QListWidgetItem*&, myNewWidget*&)'
     ui->dayRoutine->setItemWidget(item, newWidget);
                                                  ^
```

Comment: what is `ui->dayRoutine`?

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry, I should have mentioned. dayRoutine is a ListWidget.

Comment: I see that in the myNewWidget class you create 2 widgets: QLabel and QPushButton, what do you do it for?

Comment: @eyllanesc I assumed they would be encapsulated into a single QListWidgetItem and that I could add this unit to the list?

Comment: Have you created custom widgets ?, have you worked with inheritance in classes?

Comment: @eyllanesc I thought I did when I inherited the QListWidgetItem. The idea was that myNewWidget would inherit it and create a custom version that could then be added to the list but I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you want to create a `QListWidgetItem` that has a `QLabel` and a `QPushButton` and place it in a `QListWidget`?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, ideally.